# Variable scope or return issue (not sure which)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

Using the script below I'm attempting to create an object called temptagarray which gets populated with all the tags on a Tumblr weblog and their frequency.  So it should end up looking like this:

```
{'performance': 10, 'installation': 5}
```

I know the object is being created and it looks correct (I can print it out in each loop) but I can't figure out how to use it after/outside the function i.e. at the bottom of the script where I attempt to document.write() it out.  Is this a global/local variable issue, a return issue or do I need to address it in some way?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var temptagarray = {};
var tags;
var tag;            

function loadPosts () {

    var key = "api_key=9I4rZAYQCbU1o5TSMZuyrlvXiQsNxKBicCJxNK5OKZ6G9pgdim";
    var api = "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/garrettlynch.tumblr.com/";

    var retrieve_more = function (offset) {
        $.getJSON(api + "posts?callback=?&filter=image&limit=20&offset=" + offset + "&" + key,function(data) {


            //for each item (post) in the response
            $.each(data.response.posts, function(i, item) {

                //pull out the posts tags
                tags = item['tags'];

                //loop through the tags
                for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
                {
                    tag = tags[i];

                    //if the tag already exists in the tag array
                    if (temptagarray[tag])
                    {
                        temptagarray[tag] = temptagarray[tag] + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temptagarray[tag] = 1;
                    }
                }

            });

            if (data.response.posts.length == 20) {
                retrieve_more(offset + 20);
            }

        });

    };

    retrieve_more(0);  
}

loadPosts();

document.write(JSON.stringify(temptagarray));

</script>
```

Thanks in advance
Garrett

Comment: The issue is the **A** in Ajax; your write is happening before the async call comes close to finishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
if (data.response.posts.length == 20) {
    retrieve_more(offset + 20);
}
```

...with this:

```
if (data.response.posts.length == 20) {
    retrieve_more(offset + 20);
} else {
    document.write(JSON.stringify(temptagarray));
}
```

The problem you're having is that, despite your `document.write(...)` command being located below the ajax call in your code, the ajax call is asynchronous and thus the callback will be invoked asynchronously as well.  Basically, `document.write(...)` is being invoked long before you've had a chance to interact with the `temptagarray` variable in the ajax callback.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did wonder if it was happening out of order because when I put an alert in to test before the document.write it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First things first - `AJAX is Async` Asynchronous.

So the code block does not wait for the previous instruction to be completed before it executes the next line.

So your `document.writeline` would have already been executed by the time the response comes back.

Try printing that info in the success call back after the if block and you would indeed see the response.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies.  Below is what I have now as a workable solution as the result is going to call another function anyway.  Reading a little bit more I'm wondering if I should be using a callback - is it better?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//load posts from a Tumblr weblog
function loadPosts () {

    //api key and weblog address
    var key = "api_key=9I4rZAYQCbU1o5TSMZuyrlvXiQsNxKBicCJxNK5OKZ6G9pgdim";
    var api = "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/garrettlynch.tumblr.com/";

    //tags object
    var temptagarray = {};

    //all tags and each tag
    var tags;
    var tag;

    //looping function to keep retrieving posts until all are retrieved
    var retrieve_more = function (offset) {
        $.getJSON(api + "posts?callback=?&filter=image&limit=20&offset=" + offset + "&" + key,function(data) {


            //for each item (post) in the response
            $.each(data.response.posts, function(i, item) {

                //pull out the posts tags
                tags = item['tags'];

                //loop through the tags
                for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
                {
                    //pull out each tag
                    tag = tags[i];

                    //if the tag already exists in the tag array
                    if (temptagarray[tag])
                    {
                        //add 1 to its count
                        temptagarray[tag] = temptagarray[tag] + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //set its count to 1
                        temptagarray[tag] = 1;
                    }
                }
                //to test object as it gets added to
                //$("#Posts ul").append('<li>' + JSON.stringify(item, ['tags']) + '</li>')
            });

            //if the number of posts is more than 20
            if (data.response.posts.length == 20)
            {
                //retrieve the next 20
                retrieve_more(offset + 20);
            }
            else
            {
                //call the show result function
                showresult(temptagarray);
            }

        });

    };

    //stop retrieving posts
    retrieve_more(0);  
}

loadPosts();

function showresult(tagarray)
{
    $("#Posts ul").append('<li>' + JSON.stringify(tagarray) + '</li>');
    //document.write(JSON.stringify(tagarray));
}

</script>
```